# Callback after two asynchronous functions have completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I would like to call a function [addUp()] after two other asynchronous functions (updateDocument1&2) have finished. A callback after two asynchronous functions seems not to work for me....

```
/*Two asynchronous functions are now called, they both update the
the same document*/

updateDocument1();
updateDoucment2();


/* after this has been completed, I would like to call the final function
which adds two keys together of the updated document*/

addUp();
```

I am very grateful for every kind of advice/link/solution provided by you.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What language is that? JavaScript?

Comment: Of course, right now the addUp() function gets fired too early and adds up old values....

Comment: Oh sry, Javascript (written in Node, and Mongodb as the database)

Comment: Does updateDocument2 have to wait for updateDocument1?

Comment: no, just both have to be finished before addUp() is fired.
If it would just be one case, I would do update1().then(function(){addUp()})

Comment: But I do not know how to use the Promise for two functions which have to be completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use promises for this, MDN docs:

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

you can also do async/await, but thats built on top of promises anyways.

```
async function updateDocument1() { 
  //logic;
}
async function updateDocument2() {
  //logic;
}
await updateDocument1();
await updateDocument2();
addUp();
```

or

```
await Promise.all([updateDocument1(), updateDocument2()]);
```

Comment: then you can just simply say that those 2 functions are async and await for them. I edited the answer

Comment: how would I write it? Like this? : async updateDocument1(); async updateDocument1(); wait(updateDoucment1,updateDocument2) { addUp()}

Comment: async defines that the function is asynchronous, await just awaits for it to to be done, so when defining a function async function nameOfFunction(){//logic} and then when invoking just use await nameOfFunction(); //here the function is done, you dont need {} to do addup, by saying await, you will wait for the function to execute

Comment: it unfortunately says that await is only valid in async functions: await zutat1(doc, sfaktor, collection2, result.insertedId);

Comment: my function zutat1 was required from an other file. In this other file I added async. Like so: module.exports = async fucntion(doc, sfaktor, collection2,result){logic}

Comment: without typos, of course. Do you have an idea why it is not recognized as an async function?

Comment: Well, i either need a bit more info about the code so i can see whats going on, or you spend some time and read this article, it would help a lot, you will need knowledge about Promises anyways, so why not do it now:) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function. if you want, create a working plunker and we can fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I sticked to the approach with await Promise.all. I just always had one problem. "Await" can only be called WITHIN an async function. So finally, I also had to wrap the await Promise.all into an asyn function. Also I had to learn how to transform the called function from the other file into promises. But now it has worked perfectly and I have finally digged into the async/await world. Very happy, thx!!

Comment: I am new to the forum. How can I give you some props? Upvoting seems not to work as I do not have enough reputation!?

Comment: I'm really glad this helped, just marking the question answered helped me:)! Enjoy and have fun programming brother!